# Another scripts onclick function is not getting triggered when I use form.submit(), form.requestSubmit(submitBtn) or submit.click() programatically

Tags: javascript, html, forms

In the script `contact_form_2.js` a member of our team created a `submitbtn.onclick` function that handles the recaptcha interaction on all forms used on our platform.

I am working on creating a new lead form that looks for URL params in the URL, and when all of them are present and added into the form it auto submits that form.

Whenever I auto submit the form though, the `contact_form_2.js` onclick method does not get triggered. I've tried every way I can to submit the form programmatically, and none of the methods work. How can I get `contact_form_2.js`'s onclick to trigger when I submit my new form programmatically in `myscript.js`?

`contact_form_2.js`

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var submitbtn = document.querySelector(`form[name=contactform] button#submit`) || document.querySelector(`form[name=contactform] button[name=submit]`);
    submitbtn.style.display = "none";
    var lib = document.createElement("script");
    lib.async = true;
    lib.defer = true;
    lib.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=key-here";
    document.body.appendChild(lib);
    lib.onload = function () {
        console.log("recaptcha loaded");
        submitbtn.style.display = "block";
        var cform = document.querySelector("[name=contactform]");
        submitbtn.onclick = function onSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                grecaptcha.execute("key-here", {
                    action: "submit",
                }).then(function(token) {
                    var cform = document.querySelector("[name=contactform]");
                    var recap = document.createElement("input");
                    recap.type = "hidden";
                    recap.name = "g-recaptcha-response";
                    recap.value = token;
                    cform.appendChild(recap);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        document.createElement("form").submit.call(cform);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

`myscript.js`

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var basicJunkForm = document.querySelector('#basic-junk-form');
    document.createElement('form').submit.call(basicJunkForm);
    //Other attempts:
    /*
      var submit = basicJunkForm.querySelector("#submit");
      basicJunkForm.requestSubmit(submit);
    */
    //basicJunkForm.submit(); (doesn't work because my submit button is named submit, which is why I do the active work around.)
});
```

`myform.html`

```html
<form method="POST" action="/cp/resources/lib/contact_form.php" id="basic-junk-form" name="contactform" class="contactform contact-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" name="subject" id="subject" value="DRS: New Junk Removal Lead">
      <input type="hidden" name="message" id="message" value="New Junk Removal Lead">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name">
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail">
      <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
      <input  type="text" name="zip" id="zip" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip">
      <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnbdr btn-lg btn-block g-recaptcha" data-loading-text="Loading..." data-sitekey="6Lf7mtUZAAAAALRdG-q8KnHw9dh3ZZSxGMNz8zg1" data-callback="onSubmit" data-action="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-send"></i> Send Message
      </button>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="/cp/resources/js/contactform_2.js?0febd418e98f68a4f38e261004f53515" async="" defer=""></script>
<script src="/view/assets/junk_form_basic.js"></script>
```

---

Edit: Also tried this as per CherryDT's recommendation

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    var basicJunkForm = document.querySelector('#basic-junk-form');
    simulateFormSubmission();

    function simulateFormSubmission() {
        const event = new MouseEvent('click', {
            view: window,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true
        });
        const submitButton = basicJunkForm.querySelector("#submit");
        const cancelled = !submitButton.dispatchEvent(event);
        if(cancelled) {
            console.log('cancelled');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Manually trigger the event that you want

Comment: Any examples of what you mean? Not sure how to manually trigger it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#triggering_built-in_events

Comment: Interesting, this still didn't fix the issue. I call `contactform_2` before I call `junk_form_basic.js` (myscript.js) so I can only imagine the onclick is getting setup before my automated submission. The only thing I can think is somehow the onclick is getting setup after I tell myscript.js to submit automatically, but they both use window load and async defer. I'll try removing async defer and see if that has anything to do with it

Comment: Definitely not related to async defer

Comment: Oh, you are setting up the click listener only once recaptcha is loaded... which will always be after your new code which fires immediately. (By the way, I think a synthetic click won't play well with recaptcha! That click is by definition not human^^)